# Tcl how to remove only specified list item?

Tags: tcl

i need a solution to remove from a list only a specified file without removing other file.
Now i'm using follow:

```
[lreplace $var end end]
```

where $var is a directory contain a list of file Example:

```
File1
File2
File3
```

Problem is if i launch "[lreplace $var end end]" it eliminate the last file but i want to eliminate ever and only "File 3"
How i can modify it?
Thanks

Comment: If I understand , you want deleted by `name` and not by `index` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [`lsearch`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm) for the wanted list item to get its index

```
set mylist {File1 File3 File2}
set idx [lsearch -exact $mylist "File3"]
set newlist [lreplace $mylist $idx $idx]  ;# => {File1 File2}
```

If the item is not in the list, then `idx` will be `-1`, and the `lreplace` invocation will not alter the original list.

Comment: Or: `set newlist [lsearch -all -inline -exact -not $mylist File3]`. That will remove all occurrences of "File3".

Comment: It might be better to keep the list as keys of a dictionary; that has very fast deletion (`dict remove`, `dict unset`).